# I wanted to fetch all loccations within a specified area. But in json latitude and longitudes are not in GeoJson format

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have the below json data and I wanted to fetch all loccations within a specified area. But in json latitude and longitudes are not in GeoJson format. How I can use spring data criteria to fetch all locations.

```
{
"frames": [
        {
            "frame_number": 59,
            "filename": "000000984.jpg",
            "elapsed_time": "00:00:00.984",
            "elapsed_ms": 984,
            "pts": 59059,
            "latitude": 35.6504541,
            "longitude": 139.7446429,
            "altitude": 160.437,
        }
        {
            "frame_number": 78,
            "filename": "000001084.jpg",
            "elapsed_time": "00:00:00.984",
            "elapsed_ms": 986,
            "pts": 59059,
            "latitude": 35.6504551,
            "longitude": 139.7446479,
            "altitude": 160.437,
        }
        {
            "frame_number": 93,
            "filename": "000001284.jpg",
            "elapsed_time": "00:00:00.984",
            "elapsed_ms": 989,
            "pts": 59059,
            "latitude": 35.6504521,
            "longitude": 139.7446489,
            "altitude": 160.437,
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can use spring data criteria to fetch all locations??

Comment: There are two problems here: 1) I don't know about Spring data, but in your present format, MongoDB will not recognize those `latitude` & `longitude` as locations. You will need to refactor your documents to conform to proper GeoJSON if you want them to be treated as location. 2) You have an array of locations, which won't be able to be indexed by MongoDB geo features. You need one location per document, so further refactor of your data is needed.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha The 2. Statement is not entirely true. MongoDB will quite happily work with Geospatial coordinates within an array either in legacy or GeoJSON form. The *"catch"* is that finding results may not always return what you expect, as "nearest" will only ever apply to **one** array member at most. So whilst it would be "recommended" to separate location documents for *most* purposes, it is not actually a *requirement* that you *need* as you put it. Note, the "matching element" is actually a `$geoNear` feature.

Comment: @NeilLunn you are right, although I would suggest the OP to not use an array for geo locations since it could create confusion as you mentioned. At least not until the repercussions and the behaviour of arrays and geo is fully understood :)